# Please what font is this brush script?

Tags: font-identification

I have been searching for this font for ages. I remember seeing it years ago, but I can't for the life of me find out what it is called. All I know is that it is a free font. I have tried all the online tools (including What The Font and What Font Is, and still can't seem to find it. It's from a client's previous artwork that we'd like to replicate.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There are literally thousands of these script style fonts. Unfortunately automatic font ID sites don't really work so well for these kind of fonts. You will probably have to search manually through lists of fonts until you find a match. If it's a free font, then perhaps [start doing your search on Dafont](https://www.dafont.com/mtheme.php?id=6&text=Film+Gala&fpp=100) - Good luck!

Comment: I've been searching on Dafont for days and still couldn't find it. The problem seems to be finding the combination of the style of the F in the Film and G in the Gala

Comment: Yes, there are lots and lots of them to look through. There's also a possibility that the letters are not actually a font you can download, but have been hand drawn.

Comment: @BillyKerr That's possible but unlikely here, as both lower-case Ls are the same, as are the As. That said, neither WhattheFont nor Identifont can find it. Seedorf, to use font-matching services, you may need to know that you have to separate the letters so that each will fit into its own rectangle. Or you may have done that already. The F and G are distinctive and already separated, at least.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I don't think that would make it unlikely. You can easily create letters like that in software such as Illustrator, and simply copy and paste a letter when you need it again. I 've done this kind of thing often.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's either

[image]

[Amston Villa](https://www.whatfontis.com/CF_Amston-Villa.font?text=FimGal)

or

[image]

[Bulgatti Regular](https://www.whatfontis.com/CR_Bulgatti-Regular-otf-400.font?text=FimGal)

With some manual vector tweaks after the fact.

Hope that helps.